# Unity 3D Jumping issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been following along with a 3D shooter tutorial (pretty good so far) but I've hit a snag when it comes to my framerate and jumping. The framerate on my PC is just not consistent and consequently the jump height varies constantly and sometimes the character doesn't jump at all. I know handling jumping in Update (rather than FixedUpdate) can cause issues regarding framerates but the tutorial insists that using Time.deltaTime should resolve that. Any ideas on what I should do to try and keep my jumps consistent?

```
 //Jumping
public float jumpHeight = 10f;
public Transform ground;
private bool readyToJump;
public LayerMask groundLayer;
public float groundDistance = 0.5f;

// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{
    Jump();
    PlayerMovement();
    CameraMovement();
    Shoot();

}
    


void PlayerMovement()
{
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = x * transform.right + z * transform.forward;

    myController.Move(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);


    
    //9.8 meters/second^2
    velocity.y += Physics.gravity.y * Mathf.Pow(Time.deltaTime, 2) * gravityModifier;
    if (myController.isGrounded)
    {
        velocity.y = Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;
        
    }



    myController.Move(velocity);
}

private void CameraMovement()
{

    float mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    cameraVerticalRotation -= mouseY;
    cameraVerticalRotation = Mathf.Clamp(cameraVerticalRotation, minVertCameraAngle, maxVertCameraAngle);
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

    myHead.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(cameraVerticalRotation, 0f, 0f);

}


void Jump()
{
    readyToJump = Physics.OverlapSphere(ground.position, groundDistance, groundLayer).Length > 0;
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && readyToJump)
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * Physics.gravity.y) * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    myController.Move(velocity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling the acceleration yourself is a bad idea, especially in `Update` rather than `FixedUpdate`. You should know that, in real life, the velocity changes smoothly with the acceleration against time. If you draw a curve, it is a straight slope. However, in computer, if you just calculate the velocity frame by frame, the curve will be looked like stairs.

You may use the physics engine in Unity and add an instant velocity to the character when it jumps. Just let Unity handle the acceleration.

First, you need to add a `Rigidbody` component to it. Then, you may modify your code to:

```cs
private Rigidbody rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Jump()
{
    readyToJump = Physics.OverlapSphere(ground.position, groundDistance, groundLayer).Length > 0;
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && readyToJump)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector3.up * jumpHeight * 2f / -Physics.gravity.y * gravityModifier;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove the code in `PlayerMovement` on handling falling after you have `Use Gravity` in the `Rigidbody` component.

**Edit**

If you are using `CharacterController`, you can only handle the acceleration yourself. You may just move the logic to `FixedUpdate` to solve the various height problem, or make a more accurate simulation. For example, use this to handle jumping:

```cs
velocity.y = jumpHeight * 2f / -Physics.gravity.y * gravityModifier;
```

and use this to handle falling:

```cs
myController.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime + Physics.gravity * Mathf.Pow(Time.deltaTime, 2) / 2f * gravityModifier);
// Here you should check whether it will fall through the ground.
// If no, use this line to update the velocity.
velocity.y += Physics.gravity.y * gravityModifier * Time.deltaTime;
// Otherwise, update the position to make it on ground and set velocity.y to 0.
```

Comment: I'm using CharacterController rather than RigidBody. It got cut off when I pasted it over, but it's named myController;

Comment: You may still add `Rigidbody` component to the game object when you're using `CharacterController`.

Comment: I tried the modifications but jump doesn't work at all now. I checked and rb.velocity is changing, but the character isn't moving vertically at all.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that wrong message. It seems that you can only use either `Rigidbody` or `CharacterController`. Let's handle jumping and falling in `FixedUpdate` if you want to keep using `CharacterController`. Using `Time.deltaTime` in `Update` cannot resolve the various height problem.

Comment: I kept the input check in update and moved both the falling and jumping into fixed update which seems to have resolved the issue. Thanks.